# Getting rid of the command prompt window in win32

Tags: c++, c, cmd, mingw, winapi

I just built a standard win32 applicaion but when I run it, there is a command prompt

how can I get rid of that cmd window?

I am not using an IDE
I am just using notepad++ to edit

and mingw to compile through the command prompt

I am doing the g++ command to compile

should I use a different one?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `-mwindows` to your linker flags.

Comment: From the link that Noah Roberts provided: -mwindows is depreciated, you want -Wl,-subsystem,windows

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have WinMain as your entry point.

See this basic article in MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381406(VS.85).aspx

This follow up link is also helpful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381409(v=VS.85).aspx